# Jenkinsfile: monorepo with package dependencies

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, npm-publish

I am creating a [**monorepo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo) which builds and publishes **multiple npm packages** to a local Artifactory. All within this monorepo, several npm packages have dependencies with another npm package create.

The layout for this monorepo is as follows, and **npm package `@ds/cy-uncaught-exceptions-task`** has a dependency on **npm package `@ds/cy-log-task`**.

```
├── Jenkinsfile
├── packages
│   ├── cy-browser-launch-task
│   ├── cy-ds-thycotic-task
│   └── cy-log-task
└── renovate.json
```

Jenkins pipeline fails: **continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge — This commit cannot be built**
[image: Jenkins pipeline]

Jenkins build fails during the publishing of **npm package `cy-uncaught-exceptions-task`**:
[image: Jenkins Build failure]

Jenkins Publishing Error:
[image: Jenkin Package Publish failure]

This is the **`Jenkinsfile`** that performs this publish:

```
def packages = [
  '@ds/cy-ds-thycotic-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-ds-thycotic-task'
  ],
  '@ds/cy-uncaught-exceptions-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-uncaught-exceptions-task'
  ],
  '@ds/cy-log-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-log-task'
  ]
]

def conditionals = [
  [
    condition: { env.TARGET_BRANCH == 'master' && env.SCM_ACTION == 'commit' },
    overrides: [
      nodejsPublish: true,
      pushVersionTag: true,
      applicationPackages: packages.collectEntries { key, value -> [(key): value + [
        bumpPatchVersion: true
      ]] }
    ]
  ],
  [
    condition: { env.TARGET_BRANCH == 'master' && env.SCM_ACTION == 'pull_request' },
    overrides: [
      nodejsPublish: true,
      applicationPackages: packages.collectEntries { key, value -> [(key): value + [
        publishArgs: '--tag pr',
        versionSuffixValue: { 'pr.' + env.ARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER }
      ]] }
    ]
  ]
]
```

**What do I need to do to `Jenkinsfile` perform this build?**

Thank you, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: looks like it's an npm error right?  why do you think it related to the pipeline?

Comment: This is will be nice to see npm log file from /home/jenkins/.npm/npm-cache/_logs

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using **[lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)**

Install these npm packages:

- [lerna](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna)
- [@lerna/bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/bootstrap)
- [@lerna/version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/version)

**Jenkinsfile** remains the same:

```
def packages = [
  '@ds/cy-ds-thycotic-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-ds-thycotic-task'
  ],
  '@ds/cy-log-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-log-task'
  ],
  '@ds/cy-uncaught-exceptions-task': [
    projectDir: 'packages/tasks/cy-uncaught-exceptions-task'
  ]
]

def conditionals = [
  [
    condition: { env.TARGET_BRANCH == 'master' && env.SCM_ACTION == 'commit' },
    overrides: [
      nodejsPublish: true,
      pushVersionTag: true,
      applicationPackages: packages.collectEntries { key, value -> [(key): value + [
        bumpPatchVersion: true
      ]] }
    ]
  ],
  [
    condition: { env.TARGET_BRANCH == 'master' && env.SCM_ACTION == 'pull_request' },
    overrides: [
      nodejsPublish: true,
      applicationPackages: packages.collectEntries { key, value -> [(key): value + [
        publishArgs: '--tag pr',
        versionSuffixValue: { 'pr.' + env.ARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER }
      ]] }
    ]
  ]
]
```

**lerna.json** is defined:

```
{
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "npmClientArgs": [
    "--registry",
    "https://npm.docusignhq.com"
  ],
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "ignoreChanges": [
        "**/.spec.*",
        "**/*.md",
        "**/tsconfig*.*"
      ],
      "registry": "https://npm.docusignhq.com"
    }
  },
  "packages": [
    "packages/tasks/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

The monorepo's base **package.json** has these scripts:

```
    "prebuild": "lerna run audit:npm --stream && lerna run code:clean --stream",
    "build": "lerna run build --stream",
    "clean": "lerna clean",
    "code:check": "lerna run code:check --stream",
    "code:clean": "lerna run code:clean --stream",

    "postinstall": "lerna bootstrap",
```

And each package build **package.json** has the following scripts:

```
    "audit": "npx npm-run-all audit:*",
    "audit:depcheck": "depcheck --specials=bin,eslint,istanbul,jest,mocha --ignore-patterns=node_modules --ignores=@types/*,eslint-*,@typescript-eslint/*,ts-node,husky",
    "audit:npm": "npm audit",
    "audit:npm-check-updates": "npx npm-check-updates --errorLevel 1",
    "prebuild": "npm run audit:npm && npm run code:clean",
    "build": "npx npm-run-all build:*",
    "postbuild": "npm run audit:depcheck",
    "build:only": "tsc",
    "code:check": "gts lint",
    "code:clean": "gts clean",
```

audit of dependencies occurs with each build, and if it fails then an audit upgrade is performed, a new install, and a completely new local build.

This assures that builds fail locally if dependencies fail before monorepo is committed to GitHub and it expected Jenkins build.